# App terminated without notice on iOS 10

Tags: ios, background, crash, refresh, ios10

I developed an app for iOS with background refresh capability.
I recompiled the app to target iOS 10.
Since then, my app is regularly terminated silently, while in suspended state, without any notice (no willTerminate get called, no jetsam event, no crash log).

It used to work well on iOS 9.
I have upgraded to 10.0.2 but see no real difference with 10.0.1.

Anyone is experiencing the same issue ? or suggestion where I should investigate ? without any report, I am completely blind and have no more idea.

And without the background refresh, my app has a major feature not working.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Philippe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some changes to how iOS handles permissions in iOS 10. If the `info.plist` doesn't contain the appropriate keys, apps will crash silently on iOS 10.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html

> You must statically declare your app’s intended use of protected data classes by including the appropriate purpose string keys in your Info.plist file. For example, you must include the NSCalendarsUsageDescription key to access the user’s Calendar data. If you don’t include the relevant purpose string keys, your app exits when it tries to access the data.

More info on the `info.plist` changes that need to be made can be found here:
https://blog.xamarin.com/new-ios-10-privacy-permission-settings/?utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=blog&utm_source=facebook&utm_content=ios10-privacy

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I do not access any user data (nor camera, reminder, calendar, contact, etc...). And if I understand the Apple statements, the app is terminated when accessing those data ; so it would be done always at the same location in my code which is not the case. My app is terminated while it is in "suspended" state and despite the background refresh capability, it is never restarted.

Comment: Interesting. Our app didn't access the Calendar data either, but we still had to add the keys to avoid a silent crash.

Comment: I implemented what you suggested ; since Friday, my app did not crash. So, I don't understand why, but it seems your solution  is the answer !